# C# unmanaged function calls, Possible data loss, Ascii Vs. Unicode, Chinese folder names

Tags: c#, unicode, localization, dllimport, cjk

So here is the deal, Im working a C# application that calls into a legacy C++ dll, which in turns loops through a directory pulling back the names of certain directories, i.e directories that have .lib, I have a directory with the following 3 folders: Default.Lib,中文文本帧的文件.lib,我们的.lib.

As you can see we have some chinese folder names, a string is built in memory by the c++ code as you can see below, it use strcat to build it in memory. however when control is returned back to the c# code, it appears part of that data is lost and the only two folders left are the first two. Default.Lib,中文文本帧的文件.lib, something with 我们的.lib gets lost in translation, I would greatly appreciate any insights anyone may have. thanks.

C# code snippet

```
 lock (padLock)
            {
                ConnectSign(service);

                int size = MaxFileListSize * 100;
                byte[] mem = new byte[size];
                string finalList;
                int used = size;
                int fileCount = 0;
                string library = "*";
                string extension = "*";
                V7_FILE_LIST_TYPE type = V7_FILE_LIST_TYPE.LibraryList;

                fixed (byte* listbytes = mem)
                {
                    int error = NativeMethods.GetFileDirInfo(sign, type, fileServer, library, extension, &fileCount, listbytes, &used);
                    if (error != 0)
                        throw new V7ResponseException(error, sign, service, "GetFileDirInfo");
                }

                finalList = Encoding.Default.GetString(mem, 0, (int)used);

                string[] libraryArray = finalList.Split(new char[] { '\n', '\0' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for (int i = 0; i < libraryArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    int index = libraryArray[i].LastIndexOf(".lib", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    if (index > 0)
                        libraryArray[i] = libraryArray[i].Substring(0, index);
                    //libraryArray[i] = libraryArray[i].Trim().ToLower(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Replace(".lib", string.Empty);
                }

                return libraryArray;
            }

[DllImport("V7SSRpc.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, EntryPoint = "V7ssGetFileDirInfo", BestFitMapping = false, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
            public static extern int GetFileDirInfo(string sign, V7_FILE_LIST_TYPE type, string fileServer, string library, string extension, int* fileCount, byte* files, int* bytesUsed);
```

[image]
*****************************C++ DLL code--------------------------------------

```
   //--------------------------------------------------------------------
    // RETURN :
    //
    // PARAMS : eListType
    //              szServer
    //              szLib
    //              szExt
    //              *pdwFileCnt
    //              *pbyFileBuf
    //              *pdwFileBufSize
    //
    // REMARKS:
    //
    BOOL CVSign::apiGetFileDirInfo(V7_FILE_LIST_TYPE eListType, LPCSTR szServer, LPCSTR szLib, LPCSTR szExt, 
                                             DWORD *pdwFileCnt, char *pbyFileBuf, DWORD *pdwFileBufSize) const
    {
        BOOL bReturn=TRUE;
        CString sServer(szServer);
        CString sLib(szLib);
        CString sExt(szExt);
        CString sFileInfo, sTemp;
        CStringArray asFiles;
        CFileStatus status;
        CV7Files V7Files;
        DWORD dwBufUsed=0;

    // SOME OTHER LOGIC (not posted)

        USES_CONVERSION;

        //CoInitialize(NULL);
        //AVIFileInit();

        CString sFilePath;
        CV7SequenceFile V7Seq;

        CV7FileInfo fileInfo;

        // go through list of files and build the buffer with file names and other info
        for (nFile=0; nFile<nFiles; nFile++)
        {
            // MORE OBSCURED LOGIC

            sFileInfo += _T("\n");

            // add file info to buffer
            int nLen = sFileInfo.GetLength();
            if (dwBufUsed+nLen<*pdwFileBufSize)
            {
                strcat(pbyFileBuf, T2CA(sFileInfo)); //<--- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
                int nTemp = sFileInfo.GetLength();
                dwBufUsed += nTemp;
            }
            else
            {
                *pdwFileBufSize = 0;

                AVIFileExit();
                CoUninitialize();

                return FALSE;
            }
        }   // end for files

        //AVIFileExit();
        //CoUninitialize();

        *pdwFileBufSize = dwBufUsed;

        return bReturn;
    } // end apiGetFileDirInfo()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you're specifying `Charset=CharSet.Ansi`, so the default marshaling behavior is to convert the returned string to ANSI. That's going to cause a problem.

You probably want to specify string `Charset=CharSet.Unicode`, and possibly specify custom marshaling for some strings. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx#cpcondefaultmarshalingforstringsanchor5 for information on how to change the string marshaling behavior for individual parameters.

Comment: but where dealing with a pointer to a byte array would the string attributes work for that. I've tried changing the charset it just blows up.

Comment: @Nate: You're right. I misunderstood. It looks like the data coming back is correct (at least, the data dumps look correct). You're converting the data with `Encoding.Default.GetString`. Are you sure you want the `Default` encoding? That's typically an 8-bit encoding on U.S. versions of Windows. You might try `Encoding.Unicode` or, `Encoding.GetEncoding()` with the name of the proper encoding as described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getencodings.aspx.

Comment: actually the C# dump cuts the data off at element 32, the rest is null, so some how that data is getting lost, and im not sure if its in the marshalling process or what... It seems like this should be part of the problem, but im not sure. strcat(pbyFileBuf, T2CA(sFileInfo));

Comment: Yeah, that could be part of the problem. As I understand it, T2CA converts a Unicode string to an ANSI string. Then when you call `strcat`, it's going to copy up to the first 0 byte. I suspect you want to copy the Unicode string directly to the character buffer using `memcpy`.